# Facing issue while implementing CometProcessor

Tags: tomcat6, nio, comet

As per documentation under [Tomcat 6.0](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/aio.html), in introduction it is mentioned that **AJP connectors do not support Advanced IO**.

1) Does it mean that I cant use protocol **org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProtocol** (AJP NIO) to implement/use CometProcessor?

I do use Apache with Tomcat using AJP connector in my application.

Using **org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol** I can listen events in my CometProcessor implementation with HTTP port specified in Connector.

2) Is there anything missing while dealing with AJP and NIO? or I have to move to user Servlet 3.0 (Async) ?